# CircleCI Android Project (Failed to notify project evaluation listener.)

Tags: android, circleci

Had error in Circle CI when building my team's project.
[image: Error Message]
Below is my team config.yml code,

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  android: circleci/android@1.0.3

jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/bebas-capstone-2021/androidfd
    executor: android/android
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/bebas-capstone-2021
      - restore_cache:
          key: android-orb-v1-
      - run:
          name: Chmod permissions
          command: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          key: 'android-orb-v1-{{ epoch }}'
          paths:
            - ~/.android/build-cache
            - ~/.android/cache
      - run:
          name: Run Build
          command: ./gradlew build
      - store_artifacts: 
          path: app/build/reports
          destination: reports
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: ./gradlew lint test
      - store_test_results:
          path: app/build/test-results
      - store_artifacts:  
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/debug/
          destination: artifact-file
```

In my recent project it was worked perfectly but in my team project it's gave error missing local.properties file.

Can someone help me with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a way to deal with this error, we need to create local.properties file by using "touch" command, and in the end, we can delete with "rm" command or left the file alone (I don't know where was the file place even I not deleted it).

So for the detail code is below:

```
.
.
.
      - run:
          name: Chmod permissions
          command: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
      - run:
          name: Create local.properties
          command: touch local.properties
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          key: 'android-orb-v1-{{ epoch }}'
          paths:
            - ~/.android/build-cache
            - ~/.android/cache
.
.
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: ./gradlew lint test
      - store_test_results:
          path: app/build/test-results
      - store_artifacts:  
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/debug/
          destination: artifact-file
      - run:
          name: Delete local.properties
          command: rm local.properties
```

I just skipped the unnecessary code so I only showed what I changed in my last config.yml code.

I hope this solved you guys problem too.

[image: Result of my build]